# Uso de condicional para pedir algo

Tags: gramática, condicional

En un artículo en inglés https://www.realfastspanish.com/grammar/the-spanish-conditional-tense-5-uses leí lo siguiente (en los puntos 1 & 2):

"You need to be careful with the use of the conditional tense when asking for things in say a restaurant or a shop. In English, we ask for things as follows:

*I would like to have a glass of water.*

When I was in Sevilla I went into a tapas bar and asked for a ‘tortilla’ (Spanish omelette) as follows:

*Me **gustaría** tener una tortilla.* ⊗

The guy behind the bar looked at me with bewilderment.

Apart from my errant use the use of the verb ‘tener’ in this context—it may appear as more a philosophical question in Spanish than anything else (can I actually ‘have’ a tortilla?)—the conditional tense is only really used in the present for expressing politeness. While you could say ‘querría una tortilla‘ it is much better to use the conditional tense for desires that are a little more far-reaching than a plate of food just over the barman’s shoulder.

...In contrast to the previous point about asking for food in a restaurant, there are, of course, times that call for politeness.

In general, the Spanish language tends to be far more direct than English. But, there still remain situations such as speaking to a police officer, a doctor or asking for a big favor from a friend that require a touch of courtesy.

Something else to consider is the use of the usted form of the verb when you want to be polite. Simply using the usted form in Spanish expresses an idea in a more formal way. You can, thus, and probably should combine the usted form with the conditional tense.

*Would you have any information about my son’s case? = ¿**Tendría** alguna información sobre el caso de mi hijo?*"

Lo que explicó el autor, ¿es correcto? Especialmente sobre la escena en un bar donde es mejor no usar condicional? Pregunto porque vi algunos ejemplos:

"***Sería** tan amable de acomodarse en siento, Jose?*"

"*Me **gustaría** ver el menú, por favor.*"

P.S. Por adelantado agradezco que corrijan errores en mi pregunta en caso de que los haya.

Comment: **"Sería tan amable de acomodarse en siento, Jose?"** suena muy raro. "Sería tan amable de acomodarse en **su a**siento, Jose?" (?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El español parece ser más directo que el inglés, y, en mi experiencia, el español de España es aún más directo que el de Latinoamérica. En España, es frecuente usar fórmulas más directas para pedir en un bar, y no es raro tratar de *tú* a los camareros:

- ¿Me pone(s) una tortilla, por favor?
- ¿Me trae(s) una tortilla, por favor?

o incluso, si el camarero está tomando nota a toda la mesa,

- Para mí una tortilla, por favor.

El autor del artículo tiene razón en que el uso del verbo "tener" para pedir cosas es un anglicismo poco común. No decimos "¿Puedo/podría tener una tortilla?"

Para pedir cosas con más educación, aparte de usar *usted*, se usa el verbo *poder*, o el condicional. Por ejemplo, en orden de menor a mayor educación:

- ¿Me firma este documento, por favor?
- ¿Me puede firmar este documento, por favor?
- ¿Me podría firmar este documento, por favor?
- ¿Sería tan amable de firmarme este documento, por favor?

Esto vale mayormente para España: tengo entendido que en otros países latinoamericanos se utilizan otras fórmulas. Pero incluso en España, vale la conocida regla: si no se está seguro de qué fórmula usar, es mejor ser demasiado educado que ser demasiado poco educado.

Comment: Todos los ejemplos excepto el de "me pone" funcionan perfecto en hispanoamérica. Creo que hay otras preguntas aquí sobre el tema pero no las encuentro entonces anexo que en Colombia es común también decir "¿Me regala/vende/da una ...?" Obviamente da y regala se usan sin implicar realmente dar y regalar sino con la intención de comprar.